# Can anyone help me to retrieve user-top-read using Spotify API in Python

Tags: api, spotify

I am new with APIs and I am trying to write a Python code to access a user data in order to retrieve the user-top-read scope, I have registered an APP on Developer Spotify website and I have my CLIENT ID AND REDIRECT address after reading the Spotify website almost entirely I found this piece of code that I want to use but I still can't understand how to user the code with the credentials I have in order to print to a terminal an user-top-read, I know that I first need users authorization but I still can get it done, I would appreciate very much any help on this.

```
import pprint
import sys

import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import simplejson as json

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
username = sys.argv[1]
else:
print("Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],))
sys.exit()

scope = 'user-top-read'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
sp.trace = False
ranges = ['short_term', 'medium_term', 'long_term']
for range in ranges:
    print "range:", range
    results = sp.current_user_top_tracks(time_range=range, limit=1)
    for i, item in enumerate(results['items']):
        print i, item['name'], '//', item['artists'][0]['name']
    print

else:
print("Can't get token for", username)
```

That is the code I am trying to use

Answer (score 1):

This code can be run in the terminal by writing `python name-of-the-file.py yourusername` where yourusername is your Spotify username.

If you run it without setting credentials, you will get the following message:

```
You need to set your Spotify API credentials. You can do this by setting
environment variables like so:

export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID='your-spotify-client-id'
export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET='your-spotify-client-secret'
export SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI='your-app-redirect-url'
```

So, follow the directions with your Spotify App credentials from the developer dashboard!

Once you do that, run the script from the terminal again. A window will open in your browser, asking you to authenticate the app. Do that, and copy the URL it redirects you to. Copy that URL and put it into the terminal as prompted. If all goes well, you will be authenticated and the file will continue from the `if token:` block.

Friendly reminder - make sure your Python is indented properly! It will not run as you have copied it here.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness how can I set these variables in a separate file to then access them?

Comment: @fekiee Just write the above lines (substituting your values) into the terminal. EXPORT is a unix command that will set the variables so they can be accessed. You can read more about using Export here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-export-command/